# Where does Couchbase Lite store its data on Android?

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I have a particular case where I would like to access the data that Couchbase stores on the device. For the life of me, I cannot find on the device where Couchbase is storing the data. Would anyone happen to know the path?

A little perspective - I have data that comes from Couchbase with some images attached. I would like to access the path to where those images are stored so I can display them in a ListView.

Answer (score 2):

Everythihg is stored in whatever is returned by the passed Android context from `context.getFilesDir();`

The layout as of v1.2 is:

(dbname).cblite2
|
__ db.sqlite3
__ db.sqlite3-shm (possibly)
__ db.sqlite3-journal (possibly)
__ attachments
__ |
__ __ (all attachment files)

Be warned though that they will *not* be stored as the file name you selected, but rather as a hash of their contents.  You might be better off getting the data directly from the document.

Answer (score 0):

With Couchbase Lite 2.6 the database location is managed by the DatabaseConfiguration ("config" in the following example).

```
...
CouchbaseLite.init(context)
DatabaseConfiguration config = new DatabaseConfiguration();
Database database = new Database("myDatabase", config);
String dbLocation = config.getDirectory();
String dbPath = database.getPath();
```

As @borrden pointed out, this location points to context.getFilesDir() per default.

If you want to access the File object directly (e.g. for locally renaming the database) do not forget the file name suffix ".cblite2" e.g.

```
File oldDatabaseFile = context.getFileStreamPath("oldDatabaseName.cblite2");
File newDatabaseFile = context.getFileStreamPath("newDatabaseName.cblite2");
boolean success = oldDatabaseFile.renameTo(newDatabaseFile)
```